# Coding for observation space using a list of values (openai gym)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have a tuple of tuples as my observations space that each item corresponds to an action for that space.

Think of a long panel with button that can have multiple discrete values and I can switch any one of them. If the panel has 10 items then my action spaces is

self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(10)

What I want to do is simplify my observation_space in such a way that I can provide my list of discrete values. How do I define that?

PS: my observation space is currently a list of 10 values (categorical), each distinct within its space. e.g., the first can take only A and B, the second can only take C and D, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Multi Discrete Action Space](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/spaces/multi_discrete.py)